# SQL Select Minimum Value And Add Back To Table

Tags: sql, group-by, min

```
TABLE1
STUDENT SUBJECT DATE    WANT
1   HISTORY 1/1/2020    11/3/2019
1   HISTORY 11/3/2019   11/3/2019
1   HISTORY 12/1/2021   11/3/2019
2   HISTORY 3/4/2019    3/4/2019
2   HISTORY 2/6/2021    3/4/2019
3   HISTORY 1/8/2022    1/8/2022
```

I Have TABLE1 which has STUDENT SUBJECT and DATE and I wish to add COLUMN, WANT which takes the MINIMUM(DATE) for each STUDENT.

I can do:

```
SELECT STUDENT, SUBJECT, MIN(DATE) AS WANT
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY STUDENT
```

which gives me

```
STUDENT MIN(DATE)
1   11/3/2019
2   3/4/2019
2   1/8/2022
```

but How I add it back to get the desire output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your existing table, you could run the following UPDATE statement where you JOIN the source table with your SELECT query:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT STUDENT, SUBJECT, MIN(DATE) AS WANT
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY STUDENT
) t2
ON t1.STUDENT = t2.STUDENT

SET t1.DATE = t2.WANT
```

If instead you want to insert your query into a new table instead of updating, you could run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE
SELECT STUDENT, SUBJECT, MIN(DATE) AS WANT
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY STUDENT
```

Note `NEWTABLE` would need to be [created](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_create_table.asp) first before running the above query.

Comment: thank you very much; can i do it by not doing update? I wish to just generate  a new table and not modify the old one

Comment: Ah yes of course! In that case, you would use an INSERT function instead. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @bvowe If this answers your question, do please mark the question as answered by clicking the tick icon to the left of the answer. This lets others know that the question has been resolved :)